# TextBox cursor position always 0 after databinding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, textbox, cursor

I have the simple following command:

```
me.textbox1.databindings.clear
me.textbox1.databindings.add("text",TicketsBindingSource,"TicketSubject")
```

the command exeutes succesfully and I can see in the textbox the title, but once I click on the textbox1 the position of the cursor it's always moving to the position 0 and not to the area of the textbox I clicked. For example my textbox has the following text: `"Hello World"`.  If I click with my mouse inside the textbox at the letter W or anywhere I click the cursor is moving to the 0 index. eg. at the beginning, in order to move my cursor left or right I have to do that with my keyboard arrows keys.

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

```
public sub LoadTicket(byval TicketID as integer)

    Dim CmdString As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from CRMTicketDetails where ID=" & TicketID, ConnestionString)

    TicketTA.SelectCommand = CmdString
    TicketDS.Clear()
    TicketTA.Fill(TicketDS, "MyTable")
    TicketsBindingSource.DataSource = TicketDS.Tables("MyTable")
    TicketBuilder.DataAdapter = TicketTA 

    me.textbox1.databindings.clear
    me.textbox1.databindings.add("text",TicketsBindingSource,"TicketSubject")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i finally track my problem and this is very strange. 
my form has the following settings

```
        With Form_
            .TopLevel = False
            .MdiParent = MainForm
            .Parent = MainForm.SplitContainer1.Panel2
            .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Show()
            .BringToFront()
        End With
```

short version of fixing the problem

```
form.borderstyle=none
```